# How to parse JSON passed through Query Params in Angular 5

Tags: arrays, json, angular, query-string

I have a JSON of the form -

```
    { route: 'fullbody', 
        workout: [
           [{exercise:'Squat', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}, {exercise:'Row', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}, {exercise:'Deadlift', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}, {exercise:'Plank', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}],
           [{exercise:'OHP', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}, {exercise:'Row', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}, {exercise:'Deadlift', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}, {exercise:'Plank', sets:'3', reps: '8-12'}]
        ],
        title: 'Full Body Workout', 
        features: ['easy','3 times week','beginner'], 
        image: 'https://c8.alamy.com/comp/EDYW5M/portrait-of-a-bodybuilder-with-muscular-physique-posing-against-black-EDYW5M.jpg'
}
```

I have passed it to Dynamic Child Route as a Query Parameter after JSON.Stringify
(Since Arrays are not passed as Query parameter by default I have Stringified it)

Passing it like this-

```
  <a class="btn waves-effect btn-elegant waves-light" [routerLink]="workoutObj.route" [queryParams]="workoutTableParam">Use Routine <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
```

But upon retrieving the workoutTableParam in target route I am getting a JSON of this form- 
[image]

How do I parse it back to original form?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(your_json_object)` ?

Comment: Yes I did, I am getting **Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)** error

Comment: That means, you try trying to parse a string, where it should be an object.

Comment: Okay what happens when you don't use `JSON.Stringify` and instead using the json pipe like this, `[routerLink]="workoutObj.route | json"` ?

Comment: You simply wouldn't pass JSON through query params, that't not a fullbody workout btw.. :-)

Comment: Query params expects an object not a string

Comment: @bambam @user184994 passing it as `{param: workoutObj}` did work, thanks! That's a dummy workout btw :P

Comment: Just because 'it did work' doesn't mean you should do it...

Comment: I guess better approach would be communicating through services right?

Comment: Yes, for example that @AyushSingh, or using ngrx-store or something similar.